# Parameters to put in to a deleteFeatures request in a Feature Server via an ArcGIS REST API

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-rest-api, feature-service

I am trying to delete some features from a feature service using an ArcGIS REST API.  [This documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/delete-features.htm) shows the output, but I am trying to work out the input. I want to do this via code, rather than via the web interface.

I have tried these JSON parameters:
`{'objectids': [4, 5, 6]}` and `{'deleteResults': [{'objectId': 4, 'f': 'json'}]}` but they don't work.

Any ideas?

Ideally I would be deleting the features via Python. Can you do it without the API? I can post and query the feature service without accessing the 'ArcGIS API for Python' (e.g. using `requests` and `urllib`).

This is a [sample form](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ServiceRequest/FeatureServer/0/deleteFeatures).

Comment: Something like this seems to work: `{'objectids': [{8, 802, 803}]}`

Comment: It would surprise me if this format really works, it isn't even valid json

Comment: It is a version of something that I used for adding features. It sort of works, it deletes the second and third features, but not the first. I could definitely be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is just a comma separated list of objectids, no JSON.

The page you linked to has an example:

> The object IDs of the layer or table to be deleted.
>
> Syntax: objectIds=<objectId1>, <objectId2>
>
> Example: objectIds=37, 462

So you need to make a POST request to: https://example.com/arcgis/rest/services/MyService/0/deleteFeatures, with `objectIds=37,462` in the request body

The easiest way to check the format of such requests is to use the html interface of the service. Open https://example.com/arcgis/rest/services/MyService/0?f=html in a browser, then click on *Delete Features*, enter some ID's: 1,2,3,4 and use the F12 Developer Tools to see the actual request

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go a bit later.

Comment: I couldn't work out where in the Developer Tools to see the format of the request, but I edited the JSON posted based on your advice.

Comment: It's on the Network tab